# Exercise 1.15 from Brezis 'Functional Analysis', Convex sets and Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I have the next exercise:

> Let $E$ a normal vectorial space and let $C\subseteq E$ a convex set
> such that $0\in C$. Lets \begin{eqnarray*}
>      C^{\star} &=& \{f\in E^{\star}:\langle f,x\rangle\leq1,\forall x\in C\}\\
>      C^{\star\star} &=& \{x\in E:\langle f,x\rangle\leq1,\forall f\in C^{\star}\}\\ \end{eqnarray*}
>
> 1. Prove that $C^{\star\star}=\overline{C}$.
> 2. If $C$ is a vector space, what are $C^{\star}$ and $C^{\star\star}$?.

In the first part, I did the following:

Reasoning by double inclusion: Let's see what $\overline{C}\subseteq C^{\star\star}$, let $x\in C$, then for all $f\in C^\star$ verify that $\langle f,x\rangle\leq1$, then $x\in C^\star\star$, i.e., $C\subseteq C^{\star\star}$.

On the other hand, let us note that $C^{\star\star}$ is closed: Let $(x_n)\subseteq C^{\star\star}$, note that for all $f\in C^{\star\star}$
\begin{equation*}
            \begin{split}
                \langle f,x\rangle
                &=\langle f,x-x_n\rangle+\langle f,x_n\rangle\\
                &\leq\|f\|\cdot\|x-x_n\|+\langle f,x_n\rangle\\
                &\leq\|f\|\cdot\|x-x_n\|+1
            \end{split}
        \end{equation*}
Then if $n\to\infty$, $x_n\to x$, then
\begin{equation*}
            \langle f,x\rangle\leq1
        \end{equation*}
Thus $x\in C^{\star\star}$. Then $C^{\star\star}=\overline{C^{\star\star}}$, and how
$\overline{C}\subseteq\overline{C^{\star\star}}=C^{\star\star}$, in particular $\overline{C}\subseteq C^{\star\star}$.

See that $C^{\star\star}\subseteq\overline{C}$ (we reason by contradiction
): Let $x_0\in C^{\star\star}$ such that $x_0\notin\overline{C}$. How $\{x_0\}$ is a compact set and $\overline{C}$ is a closed convex set, by Hahn-Banach-Theorem (separation) exists $f_0\in E^\star$ y $\alpha_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
            \langle f_0,x\rangle<\alpha_0<\langle f_0,x_0\rangle,\forall x\in\overline{C}
        \end{equation*}
Note that $0\in C$, then
\begin{equation*}
            \langle f_0,0\rangle<\alpha_0<\langle f_0,x_0\rangle\Rightarrow\alpha_0>0
        \end{equation*}
Let $f=f_0/\alpha_0$, then:
\begin{equation*}
            \langle f,x\rangle<1<\langle f,x_0\rangle,\forall x\in\overline{C}
        \end{equation*}
luego en particular, para todo $x\in C$ tenemos que $\langle f,x_0\rangle<1$, then $f\in C^{\star}$. By other hand, how $x_0\in C^{\star\star}$ there is contradiction
, because $\langle f,x_0\rangle>1$. Then if $x_0\in C^{\star\star}$, then $x_0\in\overline{C}$.

For the next part, I cannot interpret these sets. What would they be? A ball? Anyone have any ideas on this?

Do these sets become relevant in any later content of the functional analysis or convex analysis?

Comment: Look a little more closely at the sets: they might both be described, loosely, as closed unit balls -- but you need to think carefully about what topology they're closed in and what that means.  And yes, in Banach space theory the unit balls are critical (because of homogeneity) so getting used to looking at them and understanding them is a useful skill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is a linear subspace then $C^*$ and $C^{**}$ are as well. The trick is to observe that in this case
$$
C^*=\{ f: \ \langle f,x\rangle =0 \ \forall x\in C\}.
$$
Assume not: then there is $f\in C^*$ and $x \in C$ such that $\langle f, x\rangle \ne 0$. Now set $y:=\frac 2{\langle f, x\rangle }x \in C$. Since $f\in C^*$,
$$
1\ge\langle f,y\rangle = \frac 2{\langle f, x\rangle }\langle f, x\rangle =2,
$$
a contradiction.

What we exploited is that in the condition $\langle f,x\rangle \le 1$ we can replace $x$ by an arbitrary multiple of itself, thus we can make the left-hand side arbitrarily large, while the right-hand side is fixed.